# What is the difference between guides(fill = FALSE) and theme(legend.position = "none")?

Tags: r, ggplot2

According to this page, the following should yield *no* legend:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(
      x = vara,
      y = 0.5*..density..,
      fill = varb
    ),
    color = "black",
    binwidth = 10
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") + # this is the line of interest
  facet_wrap(~ varb, nrow = 5) +
  ylab("Density")
```

However, I still get the same legend for my fill attribute.

Using the following, I get none:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(
      x = vara,
      y = 0.5*..density..,
      fill = varb
    ),
    color = "black",
    binwidth = 10
  ) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) + # this is the line of interest
  facet_wrap(~ varb, nrow = 5) +
  ylab("Density")
```

What is the difference?

**Edit: MWE**

Shame on me. I left out the code that actually breaks the graph. However, I still don't see why.

This does not help:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  vara = seq(5),
  varb = c("y","y","n","n","y")
)

prettyplot <- function(p) {
  p <- p +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(text = element_text(
      family = "Palatino", size = 14)) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(
      margin = margin(0,20,0,0))) +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(
      margin = margin(20,0,0,0)))
  return(p)
}

p <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(
      x = vara,
      y = 0.5*..density..,
      fill = varb
    ),
    color = "black",
    binwidth = 10
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") + # this is the line of interest
  facet_wrap(~ varb, nrow = 5) +
  ylab("Density")

prettyplot(p)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your first example - can you share some reproducible  code where you still get a legend even when specifying none, please

Comment: same here, `ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, fill = cut)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 500) + 
    theme(legend.position = "none") + facet_wrap(~ clarity)` shows no legend

Comment: Sorry, shame on me. Left out the code that breaks it because I was sure the problem had to be somewhere else. Edited my question.

Comment: I think it's because you set `theme_classic()` in `prettyplot` after running `theme(legend.position="none")`, which brings back the legend. You need to remove the legend *after* setting `theme_classic()`.

Comment: Strange. I cannot find anything in `theme_classic` that seems to overwrite my setting. Good to know the solution, though.

Comment: `theme_classic` is based on `theme_bw`, which includes the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prettyplot` calls `theme_classic()` which resets the legend. Since `prettyplot` is called *after* `theme(legend.position="none")`, the legend gets restored. To remove the legend only once, you need to remove it after setting `theme_classic()`.

`theme_classic` restores the legend, because it is based on `theme_bw`, which explicitly includes the legend in its default position. Here is `theme_classic()`:

```
function (base_size = 12, base_family = "") 
{
    theme_bw(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace% 
        theme(panel.border = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
            panel.grid.major = element_line(), panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), 
            panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_line(), 
            panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(), 
            strip.background = element_rect(colour = "black", 
                size = 0.5), legend.key = element_blank())
}
```

`theme_bw` is a list of 44 plot elements, including this one: `$ legend.position  : chr "right"`, which places the legend in its default location.